# Cocoapods FMDB/SQLCipher 2.7.5 can not decrypt

Tags: ios, fmdb, sqlcipher

I've added FMDB/SQLCipher (2.7.5) to my app by cocoapods.

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'FMDB/SQLCipher'
```

And perform the code bellow:

```
- (void)decryptDBAtPath:(NSString *)path withKey:(NSString *)key {
   FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:path];
   [queue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase * _Nonnull db, BOOL * _Nonnull rollback) {
      BOOL result = [db setKey:key];
      NSLog(@"decrypt db %@", result ? @"success" : @"failed");
      //it always return YES.

      NSString *sql = @"SELECT * FROM PTypeImage";
      FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:sql];
      NSDictionary *dic = [rs resultDictionary];
      NSLog(@"query test with result : %@", dic);
      //query can not by executed. 'file is not a database'.
  }];
}
```

It's always return decrypt success, but query failed.
Any wrong in my code?

I also tryed encryption by FMDB. It seems failed. Returns encrypt success, but can be open without key.

```
- (void)enryptDBAtPath:(NSString *)path withKey:(NSString *)key {
  FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
  if ([db open]) {
      BOOL result = [db rekey:key];
      //always return YES.
      NSLog(@"encrypt db %@", result ? @"success" : @"failed");
      [db close];
  }
}
```